# Erro ao executar o AVD - The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long - Nothing to do

Tags: android, android-studio, sistema-de-arquivos, avd

Quando tento executar meu AVD, o mesmo trava na parte ilustrada na imagem baixo e retorna o erro `resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!`

Estou utilizando Mac e já realizei todas as instalações necessárias através do SDK Manager.

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque você não usa o Genymotion? é muito mais rápido do que o emulador nativo do Android Studio

Comment: @Jeiferson Eu utilizava o Genymotion mas optei em mudar para o Emulador nativo após utilizá-lo na nova versão 2.0 do Android Studio! Está rápido e com novas funcionalidades! Na minha máquina Windows funcionou normalmente mas no Mac deu esse problema que postei!